# MYSQL Select Case when query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute the below mysql query, I can't see what I am doing wrong, I expect the result from the WHEN PART of the query, whereas I am getting the result from the ELSE PART.

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
   WHEN `club_name` = '7' THEN (
      SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT mobile) from member WHERE `club_name` = '7'
   ) 
   ELSE (SELECT group_concat(mobile) from member) 
   END AS mobile 
FROM member
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the data type and some sample data for club_name in member table?

Comment: Data type is string. I have even tried removing quotes form 7, still I am getting the same result.

Comment: Looks fine. Check your data. If all records have `club_name` = 7, then the results will be the same either way. Of course, depending on the data, results could be the same anyway.

Comment: does `SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT mobile) from member WHERE 'club_name' = '7'` return any records if so what?

Comment: @xQbert Yes if I just execute the query SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT mobile) from member WHERE 'club_name' = '7' I get the expected result.

Comment: @MarcusAdams No Data in club_name contains 1 through 48 with many records against each.

Comment: I hate mysql's extended group by... Add `GROUP BY mobile`

Comment: Shouldn't the else also have a `where club_name <> '7'`?   Just seems odd to manage sets this way w/o it but you may have a valid reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a case of getting burned by [mysqls extensions to the group by statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html):

select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause

...The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. ...

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
   WHEN `club_name` = '7' THEN (
      SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT mobile) from member WHERE `club_name` = '7'
   ) 
   ELSE (SELECT group_concat(mobile) from member) 
   END AS mobile 
FROM member
GROUP BY mobile
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be410c/2/0)

WITH GROUP BY Returns (which I believe to be what your after)

```
MOBILE
abc,def,def,xyz,xyz,xyz,lmn
abc,def,def,xyz,xyz,xyz,lmn
xyz,lmn
abc,def,def,xyz,xyz,xyz,lmn
```

Without Group by:

```
MOBILE
abc,def,def,xyz,xyz,xyz,lmn
abc,def,def,xyz,xyz,xyz,lmn
abc,def,def,xyz,xyz,xyz,lmn
abc,def,def,xyz,xyz,xyz,lmn
xyz,lmn
xyz,lmn
xyz,lmn
```

To just return 1 row...

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
   WHEN `club_name` = '7' THEN (
      SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT mobile) from member WHERE `club_name` = '7'
   ) 
   ELSE (SELECT group_concat(mobile) from member) 
   END AS mobile 
FROM member
WHERE `club_name` = '7'
GROUP BY mobile
```

Comment: Actually I expect the result to be just xyz,lmn one row, how can I achieve it? as if I execute the query - [SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT mobile) from member WHERE `club_name` = '7']

Comment: You just want one row of xyz,lmn?  add a where clause `where club_name = '7'` to the outer select but then I don't see why you need the case statement

Comment: You are right, What I am trying to achieve is I am comparing the values from multiple drop-down fields and I couldn't find a way where no selection is made in a specific list, it be treated as all(including null values) I have tried to set the value of select as '%' as well but then it includes all values from the drop-down list and not the null values.

Comment: I am accepting the answer as Your answer is correct based on my question, though I couldn't achieve what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure if you try and explain the question with sample data and expected results, we can figure it out.